dlib wheel build fail
Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for face-recognition-models, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
     
      ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib
     
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

When running pip install facial-recognition I get this error when it installs dlib. I've tried to install it individually and on a venv and on WSL but I keep getting it. Not really sure what to do at this point.

oh and btw I do have cmake installed
